# Problema al Generar APK en Android con Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, ionic-framework, apk

Saludos compañeros stackers, en esta ocasión ando estudiando el framework de Ionic, revisando los proyectos básicos que el framework te permite crear por defecto con comandos por consola. Usando Visual Studio Code 1.21.1, como plataforma base Android 7 y con versión de Ionic 3, teniendo mi proyecto básico listo para construir para obtener mi apk, con el siguiente archivo config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>myApp</name>
<description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" /></widget>
```

Usando los siguientes comandos:

```
cordova platform add android@7.0.0
cordova build android
```

Hasta el momento no he podido obtener mi archivo apk para visualizar mi app en mi teléfono, obteniendo la siguiente salida por consola:

```
C:\Users\Documents\IonicApp\myApp>cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
studio
(node:8068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

He intentado borrando package.lock.json, plugin y platform, luego corriendo los siguientes comandos:

```
npm install
cordova prepare --save
```

Sin lograr éxito alguno.

Si alguien tiene alguna pista o idea sobre cómo solucionar este inconveniente, le estaré muy agradecido de que lo comparta, estoy atento a sus respuestas. Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema parece ser complejo y con multiples soluciones vayamos por partes.
Lo primero es que te genera un error esto según la información que he encontrado es por un error en cordoba, y la solución mas factible es realizar un downgrade a la version 7.1.0 o 6.4.0 con ayuda del siguiente comando 
`ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0` te anexo un link a github sobre el tema [link](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/438)

El segundo error te indica que no se pudo leer la propiedad lenght para ello te dejo una posible [solucion](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7153)

Espero te ayude

Comment: Genial, voy a aplicar tu solución y luego te cuento cómo me fue. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Agrega la parte importante de los enlaces a tu respuesta @Revsky01 ., revisa  [answer].